# Unable to webdeploy from TeamCity 8 error MSB4018: The "IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: webdeploy, teamcity-8.0

I try to create build configuration for automation project web deploying. Deploying from dev machine works well but there is an exception when running from TeamCity

```
msbuild.exe d:\projectsnet\testproject\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj /P:Configuration=Production /P:DeployIisAppPath="apps.local.company.eu/testproject" /P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://production.local.company.eu:8172/msdeploy.axd /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:UserName=COMPANY\webdeploy /P:Password=webdeploy

[15:39:37][src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity] PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder
[15:39:37][src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity] GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles
[15:39:37][GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[15:39:37][GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles] CallTarget
[15:39:37][CallTarget] CheckAndCleanMSDeployPackageIfNeeded
[15:39:37][CheckAndCleanMSDeployPackageIfNeeded] IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded
[15:39:38][IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850, 5): error MSB4018: The "IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded" task failed unexpectedly. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.CheckMSDeploymentVersion() at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.get_IsMSDeployInstalled() at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.CheckMSDeploymentVersion(Task task) at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
[15:39:38][src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity] Project src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity failed.
[15:39:38][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[15:39:38][Step 1/1] MSBuild output
[15:39:38][MSBuild output] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Common.Utility.CheckMSDeploymentVersion(Task task) [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9eabf555ebf4c4ed\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity]
[15:39:38][MSBuild output] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded.Execute() [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9eabf555ebf4c4ed\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity]
[15:39:38][MSBuild output] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9eabf555ebf4c4ed\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity]
[15:39:38][MSBuild output] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9eabf555ebf4c4ed\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity]
[15:39:38][MSBuild output] Done Building Project "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9eabf555ebf4c4ed\src\testproject.Web\testproject.Web.csproj.teamcity" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, If you would like to deploy web apps using Web Deploy from TeamCity make sure that http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy Web Deploy is installed on Teamcity server ...